# How to ignore remote notification when App runs in the foreground but handle it when clicking the notification to launch the App?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can an App ignore a remote notification while it is running in the foreground but respond to it when clicking the notification on the notification bar to launch the App？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app is in the foreground,  a notification doesn't appear in the notification bar. The notification payload is passed to the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method,  where you can ignore it if that's what you want.

When the app is running in the background when the notification arrives, when you open the app, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is also called. You can distinguish between those two cases with the following code :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if([app applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        //application was running in the background
    }
}
```

When you open the app by tapping a notification,  the notification payload is passed to a different method, called `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, where you can handle it.

Comment: but i found it is passed to the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method always.

Comment: i found it is passed to the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method always when the app is in the background. but after i kill the process,the payload is passed to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method..so,my question still has no answer.

Comment: that's cool,it works.i found that the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method is run before the applicationDidBecomeActive: method.thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this combo. Without the function I added in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, notifications won't deep link via the logic contained in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` when the app first launches into memory from a notification tap.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // All your nice startup code

    // ...

    // Hook for notifications
    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
    }
}
```

Both of these are in your AppDelegate, btw.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        return;
    }

    // Do anything you want with the notification, such as deep linking

    // ...
}
```